# Is there a principled way to distinguish between these signals?

Tags: signal-analysis, estimation

Consider these two signals:

[image]

They both describe a biological process going on in the same subject. The blue one is obtained at rest and the red one after the subject is perturbed. Is there a principled way to model change such as evinced here?

### A possible approach

Just comparing the standard deviations of the blue and red actually works well in many such cases, since the red signal is somewhat "dampened" but I am not entirely satisfied with this approach.

Comment: Your questions does not contain enough data or information about the process to give a well founded answer. You can improve it by explaining the background, your knowledge about the generating process and providing a lot more data sets.

Comment: Do you have more samples?  It looks like the period of the red trace might be shorter, but with just a couple of cycles it is hard to tell.